# String functions not working in electron app

Tags: vue.js, electron, axios, quasar-framework

I have a .js file inside an electron app that uses the quasar framework.

inside this file i have axios to make requests to my api to pull data
once i get the response i use the data for further processing. However i need some string functions to escape some strings and when i try .replace it just fails.

```
 var t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj))
 console.log(t.message.replace(/"/g, '\\"');)
```

the app just fails to build and tells me there is some error in x line. if i use console.log(t.message) i see that it print the text in the terminal console, so i know the value is not null.

Also when i hover my mouse over the variable it tells me (any) not sure what this means.

image:
[image]

P.S: this is my first time working this tech stack.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of the semicolon in your `console.log`?

Comment: @dziraf yes,  at first i thought the same, then i realised none of the lines of code in the .js file inside electron had a semicolon

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out there was a configuration issue with babel inside electron that was using quasar framework, it didn't not accept commonjs as module and hence no vanilla javascript would work.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue myself, I know you've answered your own question but if you can use nodejs you can install replace-string from npm and use it

command: npm install replace-string

link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-string

This issue has literally caused me a morning of work - but hope someone finds this post and fixes this issue quicker!